# how to replace one calaculation result to another one in a loop?

Tags: equation-solving, replacement

I am doing the calculation in a loop. I gain a digit for rzin in

```
FindRoot[-Log[
     1 + zSN] == (-Log[.7142857143 + .7142857143*rzin]*(nb + A + 
         2)*(Dd*α + A*Dd - α*b2b*A) - 
      Log[(α + α*rzin + A)/(1.4*α + A)]*(2 + 
         nb)*(α + A)*(-Dd + b2b*A) + 
      A*Log[(Dd*rzin + b2b*A)/(.4*Dd + 
           b2b*A)]*(Dd*α - α*b2b*A + nb*b2b*A + A*Dd + 
         2*b2b*A))/((Dd - b2b*A)*(Dd*α + 
        A*Dd - α*b2b*A)), {rzin, 2}];
```

and then I want to use the result for `rzin in other calculation in the same loop where I have to integrate some thing like:

`Integrate[...,{r,rzin,0}]`

My question is that how I could replace `rzin` from first calculation to the second one in a `Do` loop?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are too many things missing from your code to try it, but we can answer the question anyway.  When you do your `FindRoot`, you'll get an answer like

```
{rzin -> -1.44}
```

This is a replacement rule.  You can use it like

```
rzin - 4 /. {rzin -> -1.44}
(* -5.44 *)
```

So what you do in your loop is

```
soln = FindRoot[{.....}, {rzin, 2}];

Integrate[...., {r, rzin, 0}] /. soln
```

and it will replace `rzin` with the answer to the `FindRoot` command.

**Edit**
In your original post, you were talking about `Integrate` which works just fine, as we can see here:

```
soln = {rzin -> -14.1};
Integrate[r^2, {r, rzin, 0}] /. soln
(* 934.407 *)
```

But if you want to use `NIntegrate`, this will not work.

```
soln = {rzin -> -14.1};
NIntegrate[r^2, {r, rzin, 0}] /. soln
```

> During evaluation of In[9]:= NIntegrate::nlim: r = rzin is not a valid limit of integration. >>

```
(* 934.407 *)
```

So now you need to define a new variable that takes the value given in soln:

```
soln = {rzin -> -14.1};
dummyvariable = rzin /. soln;
NIntegrate[r^2, {r, dummyvariable, 0}] /. soln
(* 934.407 *)
```

Comment: By using this method I received this error:     NIntegrate::nlim: "r = {r->0.302005} is not a valid limit of integration."

Comment: I don't think you used the exact method I put up there.  Edit your original post to give the whole code

Comment: This is my original code I has written:\[Omega]b = 1033.;

\[Beta]b = .3;
\[Alpha] = .8;
b2b = 0.01;
nb = -0.006;
zSNvec = Import[
   ".....", {"Data", {All}, {1}}];
\[Mu]expvec = 
  Import["....", {"Data", {All}, {1}}];
\[Sigma]SNvec = 
  Import["...", {"Data", {All}, {1}}];
\[Chi]2vecSN = 
  Import["....", {"Data", {All}, {1}}];
A = -1 - nb + (1/6)*\[Omega]b*nb^2;
Dd = 3*A + nb^2 + 5*nb + 6;
 For[i = 1, i < 4, i++,
  zSN = zSNvec[[i]];

Comment: soln = FindRoot[-Log[
       1 + zSN] == (-Log[.7142857143 + .7142857143*rzin]*(nb + A + 
           2)*(Dd*\[Alpha] + A*Dd - \[Alpha]*b2b*A) - 
        Log[(\[Alpha] + \[Alpha]*rzin + A)/(1.4*\[Alpha] + A)]*(2 + 
           nb)*(\[Alpha] + A)*(-Dd + b2b*A) + 
        A*Log[(Dd*rzin + b2b*A)/(.4*Dd + 
             b2b*A)]*(Dd*\[Alpha] - \[Alpha]*b2b*A + nb*b2b*A + 
           A*Dd + 2*b2b*A))/((Dd - b2b*A)*(Dd*\[Alpha] + 
          A*Dd - \[Alpha]*b2b*A)), {rzin, 2}];
  Print["rzin" , "=" , rzin];

Comment: @Eli, go to pastebin.com and put it all there, then link the results

Comment: Integral = 
   NIntegrate[
     ......, {r, rzin, 0.4}, 
     WorkingPrecision -> 12] /. soln;
  ;
  Print["Integral", "=", Integral]
  ];

Comment: @Eli, what is the result of your `Print["rzin", "="`  command?  Also, in your original post you had `Integrate`, but if you want to use `NIntegrate` it takes a bit more effort.

Comment: I did a mistake in  Print["rzin", "=" .. as you pointed. I must wrote  Print["rzin" , "=" , soln]; now it is working. Thanks so so much for your help dear Jason B.

Comment: @Eli, if you have it working now, go ahead and [mark the question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) as solved so it doesn't show up as unanswered in the feed.